# Excel 2010 document contents not scrolling with scrollbar

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, scrolling, scrollbar

For some reason on a couple of computers, Excel 2010 is having issue with the scrollbar.

When the vertical scrollbar is dragged, the contents of the page do not follow (for example, as they do in a browser). When the scrollbar is released, Excel will jump to that position. The mouse scroll works fine.

This is annoying as it makes it difficult to quickly scroll through long spreadsheets with a visual indicator of where you will 'land'. Other Excel 2010 installations exhibit this desire behaviour.

I have searched online and nearly everything refers to frozen panes, but there are none in these spreadsheets, and the scrollbar functions as intended when viewed on another computer.

Any suggestions?

Edit: It seems to be all of Office experiencing the issue. Repair does not help. Reinstall does not help. Deleting registry keys does not seem to help. Issue only affects only single user of machine- logging on as a different user, the problem is not apparent.

Comment: Does it matter which XLSX file you have loaded? IE: does it behave differently with a short spreadsheet vs. a really long one? Are there any major differences between the machines that work as expected, and ones that don't?  GPU acceleration differences perhaps?  Aside form searching online, what have you actually tried already? Have you tried disabling GPU acceleration on the problematic ones yet?  Do they behave the same regardless of who's logged into the machine?  Have you tried repairs/reinstalls yet?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter which XLSX or XLS is loaded, and length doesn't make a difference. Each machine is identical in hardware; exact same model number and specs. Tried checking pane freezing (not enabled) and also done a repair of the Office install. Haven't tried a different user logged in, will try that tomorrow morning. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Logging on as a different domain user on the same PC, Excel scrolls as expected. It seems to be linked to the user in that case. Any suggestions? Where does Excel keep per user config?

Comment: Most of the settings are stored in the registry, under the "Current User" hive.  So while logged in as the problematic user find the Excel key (something like HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel), export it for backup, and then delete it.  Log out and back in as the user and try again.

Comment: Almost same problem here, the screen is scrolling, but no visual indicator of the position in the scrollbar except releasing the mouse. I tested the mouse. Other profile on same computer is OK. I'll test clearing registry.

Comment: I resolved by reinstalling Windows - twice! It occurred again the first time around. It worked until I opened OneNote. For some reason it was okay on the second reinstall. Touch wood.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

Excel > File tab > Options > Advanced > (Dispaly section) > Tick the "Disable harsware graphics acceleration"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Excel in particular, but for most applications this is controlled by the `Show window contents while dragging` setting.

This is in a different location depending on the Windows version.

In Windows XP, right click on the desktop and click `Properties`. Click on the `Effects...` button. Second from the bottom is the `Show window contents while dragging` checkbox.

In Windows 7, open the Start Menu, search for `Appearance`, and choose `Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows`. Go to the `Visual Effects` tab. The `Show window contents while dragging` checkbox is about two-thirds of the way down the list in the `Custom` list box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That option is enabled, but I believe it refers to dragging a windows around. Eg, turn it off, and you will move the outline of a window when you drag it, rather than the windows and its contents. :)

Comment: Hmm, yeah I remembered scrolling of window contents being connected with that setting, but it doesn't looks like even as of Windows XP that setting doesn't affect scrolling within windows.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your problem correctly, the scroll bar moves but the columns don't. If that is correct - unfreeze the panes [View Tab- Click the little arrow under Freeze Panes - choose Unfreeze Panes]. Then you can refreeze them.
Source:
http://dfarq.homeip.net/2013/10/what-to-do-when-your-excel-worksheet-wont-scroll/

Comment: The OP says *"I have searched online and nearly everything refers to frozen panes, but there are none in these spreadsheets, "*